# Merging two sides of image, with one side being an alpha map

Tags: c++

This may sound like a bit of a strange question, but it's been destroying my brain for a while now.

I have an image, that has a sequence of two frames. The second frame is supposed to be an alpha mask for the first frame.

Here is an example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtSVo.png

Is there any program out there that I could use to apply the alpha map to the first image, and spit out a single-frame PNG, if not, could anybody point me to a starting point to begin making a custom program (C++, preferably)?

I apologize if this is not an appropriate question for this site.

Comment: This question isn't really on-topic for stackoverflow. Such tool recommendations usually work better on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/). Anyway, GIMP can certainly do this, if you want a solution that can be automated, check out ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0):

You have to blend two images together.

For the first part of your question

- There are thoursands of image editors. You can do it for example `gimp`.
  I think gimp also provies command line interface called
  [batch mode](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/), which probably you can use.

For the second part of your question

- Use can use `OpenCV` library, which provides rich functionality for
  image processing.  Check [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html) the examples of blending two
  images.